# On approving asset, required field error message not showing

Tags: content-management, content-hub, field

I am experiencing a problem related to a required field, if someone ever had this problem or has some suggestions, please let me know :)

I created a DateTime type field that is required when the asset is approved, and added that condition.

Then I start by importing an Asset with success, then I submit it for approval and it goes to the Review page.
On the review page, I try to approve the asset, with the field empty, and nothing happens. I should be getting an error message on a popup saying something like "creation date is required" but nothing happens.

Did anyone ever face this problem? Thank you

Condition:
[image]

Validation is working, only the message is not showing
[image]

If using the Mass submit or approve and attach a picture this is what I get:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Only the individual Submit for Approval and Approve got problems in error notifications

Comment: Check the validation on your field and make sure you have enabled validation for workflow

Comment: Can you show us how you have applied validation?

Comment: @SitecorePro where do I check that?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal thank you for your response. I added a image with the condition